# OpenGL error thrown by fragment shader

Tags: opengl, shader, opentk

I'm writing a 2D game in OpenTK, using OpenGL 4.4. Using colour and texture UV coordinates and a matrix I can succesfully draw textures between vertices with vertex shader:

public const string vertexShaderDefaultSrc =
            @"
            #version 330

```
        uniform mat4 MVPMatrix;

        layout (location = 0) in vec2 Position;
        layout (location = 1) in vec2 Texture;
        layout (location = 2) in vec4 Colour;

        out vec2 InTexture;
        out vec4 OutColour;

        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = MVPMatrix * vec4(Position, 0, 1);
            InTexture = Texture;
            OutColour = Colour;
        }";
```

and fragment shader:

```
public const string fragmentShaderDefaultSrc =
    @"
    #version 330

    uniform sampler2D Sampler;

    in vec2 InTexture;
    in vec4 OutColour;

    out vec4 OutFragColor;

    void main()
    {
        OutFragColor = texture(Sampler, InTexture) * OutColour;

        //Alpha test
        if(OutFragColor.a <= 0) 
            discard;
    }
    ";
```

BUT if I want to draw just a solid colour rather than a texture, I use this shader (with the same vertices, passing UV coords that won't be used):

```
 public const string fragmentShaderSolidColourSrc =
    @"
    #version 330

    uniform sampler2D Sampler;

    in vec2 InTexture;
    in vec4 OutColour;

    out vec4 OutFragColor;

    void main()
    {
        OutFragColor = OutColour;

        //Alpha test
        if(OutFragColor.a <= 0) 
            discard;
    }
    ";
```

Now this works beautifully, but OpenGL reports an error - GL_INVALID_VALUE. It draws fine and everything seems to work, but ideally I would like OpenGL to be error free in that situation, so I can catch real errors. I would appreciate any help, and can share more detail of how the shader is compiled or used if that is helpful - what I don't understand is how the default shader can work but the solid colour doesn't.

I have tracked down the exact source of the errors in my render call (shader builds with no problems)

```
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(shader.LocationPosition);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(shader.LocationPosition, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Stride, 0);
        //-----everything up to here is fine

        //this line throws an error
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(shader.LocationTexture);
        //as does this line
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(shader.LocationTexture, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Stride, 8);


        //this is all ok
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(shader.LocationColour);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(shader.LocationColour, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.UnsignedByte, true, Stride, 16);

        //ok
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, indexBuffer);
        GL.DrawArrays(DrawType, 0, Vertices.Length);

        //ok
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(shader.LocationPosition);

        //this line throws error
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(shader.LocationTexture);

        //this is ok
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(shader.LocationColour);
```

Comment: When does OpenGL report the error ? Shader compilation ? Shader linking ? Binding ? Drawing ? Can you provide the code surrounding the error ?

Comment: Edited to show exact source of error (in rendering).

Comment: This would suggest that shader.LocationTexture has an invalid value. You should check the line where you initialize it. Otherwise, if you don't need texture, you don't need texture coordinates either.

Comment: Some (all?) OpenGL implementations don't like unused uniforms and you don't reference `Sampler` in your second shader variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me after some tests (would be nice to have this verified) that if a variable such as the texture coordinates are not used by the shader the compiler gets rid of it, so a call to get it's location returns -1. Simply checking if locationTexture was -1 here and then not binding locationTexture etc if so resolved my issues.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case. Only _active_ attributes (same for uniforms) do have a location. The shader compilers/linkers are typically very aggressive in optimizing out everything which does not influence the final outputs. Note that for uniforms, setting a uniform with location -1 is explicitely defined as not an error (it is just silently ignored), but for attributes, this is different. The location you can query is a signed int and might be -1, but the index for the vertex attrib functions is unsigned, and using indices outside the [0, max_attrib-1] range is always an error.